# ReWrite RegEx, URL having at least one character

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, httpd.conf

I have the following RewriteRule:

```
RewriteRule ^/people/([A-Za-z0-9\-\_]*)/?$  /people/people_details.cfm?person=$1 [I,L]
```

...it works great for forwarding my rule, but I want to make sure that the regex only picks it up if it has more than one character.  So really, I need to have my regex...

```
[A-Za-z0-9\-\_]+
```

...have an additional rule to say that there has to be at least one character.  Right now if I go to...

```
/people/
```

...it should go to the default document index.cfm, but because of the rule, it still tries to forward to my people_details.cfm

Any help?

Thanks,
George

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regular expression that you put in your question already ensures that there must be at least one character. The `+` means "1 or more", as opposed to `*` which means "zero or more". Just change the `*` to a `+`.

Answer (score 0):

> ...it should go to the default document index.cfm, but because of the rule, it still tries to forward to my people_details.cfm

Thats because you have the "/" as optional at the end, which is probably not what you wanted.